# Не выходит авторизация кириллицей

Tags: php

```
ниже представлен код авторизации который латинскими буквами с цифрами нормально работает, вот с кириллицей нет, какое правило для этого нужно составить? еще было бы идеально если бы символы наподобие этих читало ♀↓►♥ можно было бы использовать в пароле

таблицы в mysql имеют тип utf8_general_ci

 if(isset($_POST["user_login"]) && isset($_POST["password_login"])){
    $user_login=preg_replace('#[^A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9]#i', '', $_POST["user_login"]);
    $password_login=preg_replace('#[^A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9]#i', '', $_POST["password_login"]);
    $md5password_login=md5($password_login);
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$user_login' AND `password`='$md5password_login'");
    $userCount=mysql_num_rows($sql);
    if($userCount == 1) {
    while($row= mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $id=$row["id"];
    }
    $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
    $_SESSION["user_login"]=$user_login;
    $_SESSION["password_login"]=$password_login;

    exit("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0\">");
    }else {
    echo 'неверный логин или пароль';
    exit();
    }
    }
```

Comment: [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 in PHP sucks. Sorry.

Попробуйте прописать это в index.php вверху.

```
// Tell PHP that we're using UTF-8 strings until the end of the script
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

// Tell PHP that we'll be outputting UTF-8 to the browser
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
```

И еще желательно прописать addDefaultCharset UTF-8 в htaccess

Comment: все тоже сообщение "неверный логин или пароль" при попытке залогинется русскими буквами

Comment: а базе у вас что? сравниваете с кракозябрами? выводите информацию на экран, смотрите что приходит.

Comment: никаких кракозябр, заносится русский текст, и так же выводится, только что посмотрел, а вот авторизироватся не хочет

Comment: запрос пустой приходит?

Comment: нет пустой не проходит

Comment: var_dump($sql) что выводит?